# Microsoft Azure server OpenSSL

Tags: php, azure, ssl, openssl, azure-web-app-service

what steps I should take to upgrade the OpenSSL version on my MS Azure web server? It's current version is OpenSSL/0.9.8zf and I need at least 1.0.1.

I have a certificate uploaded in Certificates tab here http://prntscr.com/e63ssf
Does that mean I have to buy another certificate?

P.S. I just found that the SSL version is different on PHP application if I dump it with phpinfo(); and if I go to console on Azure website - it says that the version of curl is OpenSSL 1.0.2. How can I update my PHP side?

Comment: What MS Azure web server do you mean specifically? Web App, VM, others?

Comment: Cloud service (classic), if that's what you asking. It's a php website and I need a newer OpenSSL version.

Comment: Exactly, I suggest you can update your question with this info

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. If anyone ever needs it:

The problem was that PHP application was loading an older curl extension, so I needed to get my latest php_curl.dll file and load it on my MS Azure Web app.

Just follow this tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure 
"How to: Enable extensions in the default PHP runtime".